# Different methods to use a class/struct - C++

Tags: c++, methods

```
struct Foo
{
    void SayHello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi, I am Foo";
    }
};
```

I have the above given struct. I have seen a usage like this in one of our code base.

```
Foo foo;
{
     foo.SayHello();
}
```

IMO, It does same like

```
Foo foo;
foo.SayHello();
```

Or is there any advantage/difference for the first method?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that particular case, it looks quite strange and like a candidate for review. Can be useful in other cases:

```
Foo foo;
{
    ReturnValue v = foo.SayHello();
    Send(v);
}
...
```

Where it would limit the scope of `v`. One common use is to make the objects in it destroy earlier. Classes that do special stuff in their constructor and destructor can then be used inside the braces:

```
Foo foo;
{
    MutexLocker locker(sendMutex);
    ReturnValue v = foo.SayHello();
    Send(v);
}
...
```

The lock for the send-queue would be held while sending `v` in that example, and be released when the locker is destroyed at the closing brace.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks litb.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference in the two examples. The following, however, would create and destroy the foo object within the scope of the braces:

```
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.SayHello();
}
```

This is useful for objects that follow the [RAII](http://gethelp.devx.com/techtips/cpp_pro/10min/2001/november/10min1101.asp) idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance mean that your first option is

```
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.SayHello();
}
```

That would make more sense because then the foo object is created, used, and destroyed within the smaller scope of the curly braces that wrap it. That is a common practice that aims to reduce the lifetime of transient things. Often, these sub-blocks can be refactored into separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Identical as written (as far as I can tell).

As other people have said, that construct is usually used to limit scope of something, but in your example, there's no difference.